# Need to update my table with some conditions( where statement ) using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join

From below query, I need to update my table when it comes under my conditions. The query is,

```
update tests t 
left join sites s on t.test_siteid = s.site_id 
left join companies c on c.company_id = s.site_id
set t.test_typeid = '10' 
where c.company_id = '35' and t.test_typeid = '20' and s.site_id = '1149'
```

But it shows me an error like below:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "left" 
LINE 1: update tests t left join sites s on t.test_siteid = s.site_i...
```

I did this in postgreSql. Already I tried the Same in another one method like below:

```
update tests 
set test_typeid = '10' 
where test_siteid IN 
 (
 select t.test_siteid 
 from companies c 
 left join sites s on c.company_id = s.site_companyid 
 left join tests t on t.test_siteid = s.site_id 
 where c.company_id = '35' and t.test_typeid = '20' and s.site_id = '1149'
 limit 100
)
```

But it showing an success message. But none of the row has been updated as i expected.

Kindly help me on this. There is an error when I run the first query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins in an `UPDATE` statements, but only inner joins, and you have to use the `FROM` clause for that.

If I look at your query, I see that you would be much better off with an inner join anyway, because there are conditions on both `sites` and `companies` that force them to be non-NULL anyway.

So you could just use:

```
UPDATE tests t 
SET test_typeid = '10' 
FROM sites s, companies c
WHERE t.test_siteid = s.site_id
  AND c.company_id = s.site_id
  AND c.company_id = '35'
  AND t.test_typeid = '20'
  AND s.site_id = '1149';
```

Comment: I got the error when i run your query. 
  
`ERROR:  column "t" of relation "tests" does not exist
LINE 2: SET t.test_typeid = '10' 1`. 
  
So I just adjust your query like below:
`UPDATE tests
SET test_typeid = '10' 
FROM sites s, companies c, tests t
WHERE t.test_siteid = s.site_id
  AND c.company_id = s.site_companyid
  AND t.test_typeid = '20'
  AND c.company_id = '35'
  AND s.site_id = '1149';`
  
It is showing the success message. But None of the row has been updated with value.

Comment: I fixed the syntax error, sorry. If no row has been updated, then no row met the condition. Can you find a row in each of the three tables that together meet the condition?